# Flexible Discriminant Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, statistics, lda

I am studying the book "Elements of Statistical Learning". In chapter 12 it is given about the Generalized Linear Discriminant Analysis. In one of its section it is about Flexible Discriminant Analysis.

I am not able to understand the advantage of FDA and its algorithm. Also the complex mathematical equations given about FDA is difficult for me to understand. Can anyone explain me in simple language ,how do they come to the following equations?
[image]
[image]